# Trying to get Anaconda3 running on Mac

Tags: python, macos, bash, shell, anaconda

I am trying to get Anaconda3 for Python 3.4 running on my Mac. (OSX 10.9.5) In the instructions from the Continuum Analytics after the installation this is what needs to be done.

I installed it on the home folder per instructions on this page:
http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html#mac-install

Then after the installation this is what needs to be done.
COMMAND-LINE INSTALLS:
After downloading the installer, in the shell execute:

bash Anaconda3-2.1.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
Note that you should type "bash", regardless of whether or not you are actually using the bash shell.

See -> for more info. http://continuum.io/downloads#py34

What I get back in my terminal after is this:

bash: Anaconda3-2.1.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory

What went wrong? I have sent an email to Continuum Analytics and I'm waiting for their reply. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using the GUI installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cd to the directory where the installer is first, typically `cd ~/Downloads`.

Comment: Thanks asmeurer but  step by step instruction would be more helpful.

Comment: @AtxTom I highly recommend using the GUI installer on Mac unless you have a specific reason to use the bash installer. The instructions are at http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html#mac-install.

Comment: Ok. It looks like I have to launch "launcher" and use the python-qtconsole and spyder.app to get going.  I was trying to do everything in Python interactive and run the programs.

Comment: So the GUI installer on mac is an alternative for the command line?